# Bash-like autocomplete in Windows 7 "Run..."

Tags: windows-7, windows, autocomplete

I am an usual Linux user and I got addicted to the ability of running commands from the terminal or the Run textbox (The one which has got <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> as default shortcut). In Windows 7, I'd like to work approximately the same way, using the underrated Run... textbox I can recall by Super+R shortcut.

The principal thing keeping me from using it as my principal way of starting processes is the fact I must write the entire name of the processes I want to launch. Is there a way of introducing an autocomplete feature like the one Bash has?

I'm not talking of an external terminal-like program which supports this feature, I'm talking about integrating that into the "Run..." textbox, so that I can recall it like the <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> Linux one, and start processes from a lightweight and little command line.

Comment: If you have the [inline AutoComplete option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SKVci.png) selected in Internet options (no idea why it's there and not in Explorer!) as well as the [Privacy options](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J4OBM.png) selected in Sart Menu properties, the run dialog will autocomplete commands you typed previously, and also paths you type. I think this is the best you can expect short of using some third party app that extends the feature.